# How to prompt a save dialog when user is closing a file?

Tags: .net, file-handling, process.start

I create a pdf-file, save it to a temporary location and display it with Process.Start().
Is there a way to ask the user to save the (unchanged) file when he closes it, so he can save it to a location where he finds it?
(FYI: All temporary data gets deleted when closing application.)

Comment: what platform are you targetting?

Comment: .net 2.0, from windows 7 up.

Comment: Consider this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm thinking more of opening the file marked as changed or something. I don't want to display a save dialog first. I want to click the user on "Create PDF", then the temporary file displays and when he closes it, I want to prompt for saving.